# How use appleID signin in flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies, apple-id

I used  **sign_in_with_apple: ^4.3.0** package to appleID signin this is the latest version for the appleID signin

[image]
I couldn't find any documentations how to use this version without package example code.
referring that example  I tried a code

```
  Future<void> signInWithApple() async {
    try {
      final credential = await SignInWithApple.getAppleIDCredential(
          scopes: [
            AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.email,
            AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.fullName,
          ]);

      // Get the OAuth token and ID Token
      final AuthCredential authCredential =
      OAuthProvider("apple.com").credential(
          accessToken: String.fromCharCodes(credential.authorizationCode),
          idToken: String.fromCharCodes(credential.identityToken));

      // Signing in to firebase user instance
      final UserCredential userCredential =
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(authCredential);

      // Update the user properties in the provider
      _email = userCredential.user?.email;
      _uid = userCredential.user?.uid;
      _displayName = userCredential.user?.displayName;

      notifyListeners();
    } catch (e) {
      // Handle the error
      print(e);
      _hasError = true;
      _errorCode = e.toString();
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
```

in this code show these errors..

[image]
[image]

how to resolve these errors and signin to app using appleID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `String.fromCharCodes` on a String value, also `credential.authorizationCode` and `credential.identityToken` are String values so you don't have to convert them.

Try to replace this

```
OAuthProvider("apple.com").credential(
      accessToken: String.fromCharCodes(credential.authorizationCode),
      idToken: String.fromCharCodes(credential.identityToken));
```

with this

```
OAuthProvider("apple.com").credential(
      accessToken: credential.authorizationCode,
      idToken: credential.identityToken);
```